# Adding custom HTTP headers to Wagtail pages

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, wagtail

I'm looking to make a new Wagtail site production-ready and have used some [Django security middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/middleware/#module-django.middleware.security) settings such as `SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER` and `SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS`.

One HTTP header which doesn't seem to be provided for in the security middleware is [Expect-CT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Expect-CT). I'd like this header to (preferably conditionally on (a) setting(s) in the `production.py` settings file) have a value like:

`max-age=31536000, enforce, report-uri="https://username.report-uri.com/r/d/ct/enforce"`

What would be a good way to implement this and other custom HTTP headers in Wagtail?

I have looked at the existing security middleware and tried to create my own middleware in a file within my Wagtail project, but am not sure how to reference a file/module within my project in the `base.py` file. (I'm currently a Wagtail/Django/Python beginner.) Thanks.

Edit: I expect it might be worth me attempting a pull request to the security middleware, but adding custom headers to a site on a per-project/ad-hoc basis would be something I'd like to be able to do.

Comment: Write your own Django middleware and activate it: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/middleware/ . If you like a header per page (content type) you can override Wagtail serve method https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.0/reference/pages/model_recipes.html#overriding-the-serve-method Set a response header https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#setting-header-fields Custom global settings `FOO=42` and import it `from django.conf import settings; settings.FOO`. OR user configurable settings via Wagtail https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.0/reference/contrib/settings.html

Comment: Per page setting, create a field in your Page. Eg `foo = models.SomeField(...)` and use `self.foo` in the serve method.

Comment: Thanks, @allcaps. I did start to create my own middleware but I don't know in which file to put it and how to reference it when adding to the `MIDDLEWARE` in `base.py`. For example, I get `AttributeError: module 'my_project' has no attribute 'CustomHttpHeadersMiddleware'` or `ImportError: CustomHttpHeadersMiddleware doesn't look like a module path`. Do you know the convention for this in Wagtail projects?

Comment: I think I've got it. In the file `my_app/middleware.py` I have `class CustomHttpHeadersMiddleware`, and `'my_app.middleware.CustomHttpHeadersMiddleware'` successfully loads this middleware. Apologies for the confusion. I'll write up a full answer based on your comment when it's working as intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My issue was that I wasn't aware the module path relates directly to the filename.

The following middleware creates and adds the header based on settings.

#### Location of middleware module

```
my_project
├── my_app
│   ├── settings
│   │   ├── base.py
│   │   ├── production.py
│   ├── middleware.py
```

#### `my_app/settings/base.py`

```py
MIDDLEWARE = [
    # ...
    'my_app.middleware.CustomHttpHeadersMiddleware',
]
```

#### `my_app/middleware.py`

```py
import logging
from django.conf import settings

class CustomHttpHeadersMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

        try:
            self.expect_ct = settings.CUSTOM_SECURE_EXPECT_CT
        except AttributeError:
            self.expect_ct = False

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)

        if self.expect_ct:
            response['Expect-CT'] = self.__expect_ct_header_value()

        return response

    def __expect_ct_header_value(self):
        logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

        try:
            max_age = settings.CUSTOM_SECURE_EXPECT_CT_MAX_AGE
        except AttributeError:
            max_age = 60 * 60 * 24  # 1 day
            logger.warning('CUSTOM_SECURE_EXPECT_CT setting is True but CUSTOM_SECURE_EXPECT_CT_MAX_AGE setting is not set. Default of %s applied.' % max_age)

        try:
            enforce = settings.CUSTOM_SECURE_EXPECT_CT_ENFORCE
        except AttributeError:
            enforce = False
            logger.warning('CUSTOM_SECURE_EXPECT_CT setting is True but CUSTOM_SECURE_EXPECT_CT_ENFORCE setting is not set. Default of False applied.')

        try:
            report_uri = settings.CUSTOM_SECURE_EXPECT_CT_REPORT_URI
        except AttributeError:
            report_uri = False
            logger.warning('CUSTOM_SECURE_EXPECT_CT setting is True but CUSTOM_SECURE_EXPECT_CT_REPORT_URI setting is not set. Default of False applied.')

        value = 'max-age=%s' % max_age

        if enforce:
            value += ', enforce'

        if report_uri:
            value += ', report-uri="%s"' % report_uri

        return value
```

#### `my_app/settings/production.py`

```py
# Custom middleware.
CUSTOM_SECURE_EXPECT_CT = True
CUSTOM_SECURE_EXPECT_CT_MAX_AGE = 60 * 60 * 24 * 365  # 1 year
CUSTOM_SECURE_EXPECT_CT_ENFORCE = True
CUSTOM_SECURE_EXPECT_CT_REPORT_URI = 'https://username.report-uri.com/r/d/ct/enforce'
```